# Consider defining a bean of type 'org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity' in your configuration

Tags: spring, spring-boot, grails, spring-security

While updating my existing application from Grails 4.0.6 to Grails 5.0.1 I am getting following error

*Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the conditions report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
29.11.2021 11:20:52.897 [restartedMain] ERROR o.s.boot.SpringApplication - Application run failed
org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'managementSecurityFilterChain' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/actuate/autoconfigure/security/servlet/ManagementWebSecurityAutoConfiguration.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'managementSecurityFilterChain' parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.HttpSecurityConfiguration.httpSecurity' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/security/config/annotation/web/configuration/HttpSecurityConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity]: Factory method 'httpSecurity' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Found 3 beans for type interface org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationManager, but none marked as primary*

Following are my dependencies in build.gradle

```
    developmentOnly("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-devtools")
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-logging'
    implementation "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-validation"
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-autoconfigure'
    implementation 'org.grails:grails-core'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-actuator'
    //provided 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-tomcat'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-tomcat'
    implementation 'org.grails:grails-plugin-url-mappings'
    implementation 'org.grails:grails-plugin-rest'
    implementation 'org.grails:grails-plugin-codecs'
    implementation 'org.grails:grails-plugin-interceptors'
    implementation 'org.grails:grails-plugin-services'
    implementation 'org.grails:grails-plugin-datasource'
    implementation 'org.grails:grails-plugin-databinding'
    implementation 'org.grails:grails-web-boot'
    implementation 'org.grails:grails-logging'
    implementation 'org.grails.plugins:cache'
    implementation 'org.grails.plugins:async'
    implementation 'org.grails.plugins:mongodb'
    implementation 'org.grails.plugins:events'
    implementation 'org.grails.plugins:gsp'
    implementation 'org.grails.plugins:views-json'
    implementation 'org.grails.plugins:views-json-templates'
    compileOnly "io.micronaut:micronaut-inject-groovy"
    console "org.grails:grails-console"
    profile 'org.grails.profiles:web'
    compileOnly 'org.grails.plugins:embedded-mongodb:2.0.0.M1'
    implementation 'org.grails:grails-plugin-i18n'
    implementation 'org.grails:grails-dependencies'
    implementation 'org.grails.plugins:scaffolding'

    /*For rest profile*/
    implementation 'org.grails.plugins:spring-security-rest:3.0.1' 
    implementation 'org.grails.plugins:spring-security-rest-gorm:3.0.1' 
    
    //Websocket and it's security
    implementation 'org.grails.plugins:grails-spring-websocket:2.5.0.RC1'
    implementation "org.springframework.security:spring-security-config:5.6.0"
    implementation "org.springframework.security:spring-security-messaging:5.6.0"
    implementation "org.springframework.security:spring-security-web:5.6.0"
    runtimeOnly 'org.springframework:spring-test:5.3.13'
    
    //Http clients
    String httpclientVersion = '4.5.13' //4.5.12
    implementation "org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:$httpclientVersion"
    implementation "org.apache.httpcomponents:fluent-hc:$httpclientVersion"
    implementation "org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient-cache:$httpclientVersion"
    implementation "org.apache.httpcomponents:httpmime:$httpclientVersion"
```

Comment: Code to replicate the issue is [here](https://github.com/ChiranjibKarn/chiranjibkarn-issue12376). And reported issue is [here](https://github.com/grails/grails-core/issues/12376).